# Submit button loop counter x amount of times

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Okay so i need the following to be done.

There is an input form, with 2 input fields and a submit button.
Once the values are entered, the program does a calculation and displays the sum.

The calculation (sum) then gets stored into a database, then using Ajax gets filled dynamically in another form input fields.

Is there a way that once the submit button is clicked, it automatically does it 5 times with a loop counter?

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   
var data_amount = $('#value').val();

$.when(
  $.ajax({ // First Request
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{value:data_amount},
    dataType:"text",
    contentType: false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#load_data').val(data);
    }         
  }),

  $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
    url:"fetch_another.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{value_2:data_amount},
    dataType:"text",
    contentType: false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#load_data_2').val(data);
    }          
  })
 )
});
```

**FORM**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="number" name="value" id="load_data"></input>
     <input type="number" name="value_2" id="load_data_2"></input>
     <button type="submit" name="get_values"></input>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
   $value = $_POST['value'];
}else{
   echo "Nothing Entered";
}  
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['value_2'])) {
   $value_2 = $_POST['value_2'];
}else{
   echo "Nothing Entered";
}  
?>

$result = $value * $value_2;
$result_2 = $value * $value_2 * 2000;

$sql = "INSERT INTO values(value) VALUES('".$result."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO values_2(value_2) VALUES('".$result_2."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

**FORM TO LOOP**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="number" name="value" id="load_data" hidden=""></input>
     <input type="number" name="value_2" id="load_data_2" hidden""></input>
     <button id="somebutton" type="submit" name="get_values"></input>
</form>
```

I am pretty sure that a for loop with a counter could do the trick, i am just not sure how. Also i know this can be done without the form, just for this particular case i need it to be achieved with the forms.

**I am trying something like this, which is not working out:**

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#somebutton").click(function () {
          
          for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
              $("#somebutton").click();
          }
        });   
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Surely your last bit of code is just recursive? When you click the button, it will call your function, which will then click the button, which will then call your function, and so on until the stack overflows. If you put the functionality that you actually want to execute on click (the code in your first code box) into a separate function so that you're calling _that_ function, not the button click function, does it work any better?

Comment: The first question that springs in mind: why make 5 ajax requests after oneother? What do you want to achieve?